# I want to disable native calendar for input type="date" in browser through css

Tags: css, angular

I want to remove the native calendar of the browser through CSS. Facing this problem in Firefox but I would want a solution for all browsers.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSUdu.png)

Comment: i have searched this problem for a whole day. I am unable to find a solution for firefox and other browsers.

Comment: Do you have some code you can show us, are you using Angular Material or is it your own component?

Comment: I am using Date time picker from this link

Comment: https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/

Comment: i have intentionally kept input type="date" in my input because i need the css of input type ="date" except the pop up calendar

Answer (score -2):

```
      <owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" #dt1></owl-date-time>
```

Comment: Code only answers are better with explanation

Comment: i got the answer myself. to disable control in chrome just add the following css setting

Comment: input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
While for firefox and other browsers you will have to add a event like the following

Comment: <input disabled formControlName="RegistrationDate" [class.error-field]="!isValid('RegistrationDate')" 
            class="form-control m-input m-input--square" click="onDateInput($event)">

Comment: onDateInput(event:Event)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    event. stopPropagation();
  }